# Use only a selected part from pointer with another pointer

Tags: c, pointers

so basically i want to read a text from keyboard , which i know will have the following format: "1 somewords",where somewords is a specific word.The problem is i don't know how to acces that specific part from the pointer.
For example , if i run

```
`printf("%s",myPointer);
```

my output will be only 1(the next part is missing).
I tried the assign somehow the part after " " to another pointer but it doesn't seem to work.

```
    scanf("%s",operatie); //if , for example operatie="1 dana"
    if(operatie[0]=='1') { 
        char *h=(operatie+1);   
    printf("%s",h); 
    } // h will be 0.
```

Comment: It looks to me like your string contains a null character after the initial 1. Can you look at if in a debugger? Or, can you print the first few characters casted as integer to see their value?

`printf ("%d %d %d\n", (int) operatie[0], (int) operatie[1], (int) operatie[2])`

Comment: @RichardSt-Cyr i receive the following output : 49 0 0

Comment: @PetruGurita How is the end of the input marked?

Comment: @RichardSt-Cyr with "enter" keypad

Comment: See the answer from @l3x. The explanation is correct, as can be seen by the first 0 that is printed, and the suggestion should work properly.

Comment: @RichardSt-Cyr Yes , thanks for pointing out :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
scanf("%s",operatie); //if , for example operatie="1 dana"
```

The problem is with `scanf()`. `%s` will stop at the first whitespace (after reading `1`). So the rest of the input is not read at all.

If you want to read a line, use [`fgets()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgets.3.html). `fgets()` will read the newline char too, if the inputer buffer has enough space. So you may want to remove it.

E.g.

```
   char operatie[256];

   if (fgets(operatie, sizeof operatie, stdin) == NULL) {
      /* handle error */ 
   }

   /* Remove the trailing newline, if present */
   char *p = strchr(operatie, '\n');
   if (p) *p = 0;
```